# Mirth Javascript how to check to see if a field in a segment is date or time and remove segment

Tags: javascript, mirth

In Mirth I need to check in transformer if a segment field is a date or time and
remove that segment.

tried isnan and cannot get it to work.

Comment: Show the code that you tried already.